# libtorrent and tcp::acceptor crashes with access violation on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-asio, libtorrent

libtorrent version (or branch):
master / libtorrent-1_1_5

platform/architecture:
Win32

compiler and compiler version:
msvc-14.0

boost version:
boost-1.65.1

The code below always leads to crash.

```
#include "libtorrent/session.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    libtorrent::session session;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(15));
    return 0;
}
```

Call stack:

```
>   test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::do_open(struct boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type &,int,int,int,class boost::system::error_code &) C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!libtorrent::aux::session_impl::setup_listener(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class boost::asio::ip::tcp const &,int,int,class boost::system::error_code &)    C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!libtorrent::aux::session_impl::open_listen_port(void)  C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!libtorrent::aux::session_impl::init(class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack>) C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::_mfi::mf1<void,struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl,class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> >::operator()(struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl *,class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack>)   C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,class boost::_mfi::mf1<void,struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl,class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> >,class boost::_bi::list2<class boost::_bi::value<struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl *>,class boost::_bi::value<class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> > > > >(class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,class boost::_mfi::mf1<void,struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl,class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> >,class boost::_bi::list2<class boost::_bi::value<struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl *>,class boost::_bi::value<class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> > > > &,...)    C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::detail::completion_handler<class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,class boost::_mfi::mf1<void,struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl,class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> >,class boost::_bi::list2<class boost::_bi::value<struct libtorrent::aux::session_impl *>,class boost::_bi::value<class boost::shared_ptr<struct libtorrent::settings_pack> > > > >::do_complete(class boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service *,class boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation *,class boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned int)   C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one(bool,class boost::system::error_code &)   C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run(class boost::system::error_code &)   C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!boost::asio::io_service::run(void) C++
    test-crow-libtorrent.exe!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>(void * const parameter) Line 115   C++
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12�() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8�() Unknown
```

libtorrent compile options:

```
toolset=msvc-14.0 boost-link=static dht=on encryption=on mutable-torrents=on crypto=openssl openssl-version=1.1 link=static runtime-link=static variant=debug,release i2p=on
```

Crash occurs only on release builds.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in preprocessor. Need to add `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO` when you build app (which uses libtorrent) with a tool other than boost-build.

[Here](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/2574)  you can find more information on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by building libtorrent and your test application with link-incompatible options. If libtorrent links statically against the runtime, it's your responsibility to make sure anything linking against it also does.

Alternatively, you could use a proper build tool to enforce link-compatibility (such as boost-build).